# How do I resize the container view?

Tags: iphone, ios

In this view, I have a container view (with a UITableView embedded) and an AdBannerView.

When an ad fail to load, the AdBannerView will be removed and the UITableView will be resized to fill up the rest of the screen.

Here is the problem, when I push a view into the navigation controller, and then return to this view, the extended portion of my UITableView gets cuts off. However, when I check the frame of the UITableView, it's size is remains the same.

So I figured out that the container view is causing the problem.

I tried connecting the container view to an IBOutlet but it doesn't seem to work and resizing it.  But the frame of the IBOutlet was 0,0,0,0.

[image]

Comment: Where did you check the frame? If you did that in viewDidlaod, that's too early in the process. Try it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: @rdelmar I checked at viewDidLoad. And yes, checking at viewDidAppear works! I see numbers now.

Comment: After going pushing another view into the nav controller, and popping it to come back to the same view. I checked that in viewDidAppear, the size of the container went back to the original size.

Comment: Are you using auto layout, and how did you change the size of the container view?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I'm using auto layout. And yes, I changed the sized of the container view. So, auto layout will be "reapplied" whenever viewDidAppear?

Comment: If you're using auto layout, you need to change the size of the container view by changing its width and height constraints, not by setting frames.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar! Now it's time for me to figure out how to deal with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick way to modify the sizes of the container view and the banner view by setting their frames instead of changing their constraints.

In order for the changes to work, the new frames must conform to the constraints. And also, since these constraints are reapplied whenever the view appears, I had to set the frames at `v viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

I would consider this to be a very hackish way of dealing with this problem. The recommended solution should still be to modify the constraints.